# django 'load staticfiles' failed to load HTML5 static file

Tags: python, django, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to use Django's template language to load static files into my Django template, but it seemed something went wrong. Could anyone help? Thanks in advance!

The static part I was struggling to load was this, part of bootstrap framework:

```
<img data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
```

I tried two methods in my destination template, all of which failed:

(1)

```
<img data-src="{% static "holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" %}" alt="First slide">
```

(2)

```
<img data-src="{% static "holder.js" %}/900x500/auto/#777:#7a7a7a/text:First slide" alt="First slide">
```

With this HTML5 tag, how to get it around?

Comment: `data-src` by itself isn't an attribute that will load an image file. Have you got some javascript running that uses that attribute to make a request?

Comment: Sure. In effect, it alternately shows a group of pictures in the same frame in a slide manner. I thought the `img` uses     `data-src`     to invoke the script     `holder.js`     with some specific parameters, but how to load this script, interfered by the annoying parameters, in a Django template?

Comment: how to load 'holder.js' with parameters in django template? Any excellent develper knows the solution?